# repeating transitions in d3 using setInterval

Tags: animation, d3.js

In the following code, I just have 5 bars corresponding to their values in dataset. With .each and setInterval, I am trying to have the bar fill color transition from black to red repeatedly if the corresponding value in the dataset is less than 3.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var w=500;
var h = 100;
dataset = [1,2,3,4,5];

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
        .attr("width",w)
        .attr("height",h);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("x", function(d,i){ return i*21;})
        .attr("width",20)
        .attr("height",function(d){return d*10;})
        .each(function(d){
            if (d<3) {
                setInterval(function(){d3.select(this)
                    .attr("fill","black")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("fill","red")},1000);
            }
        });


    </script>
```

When I run this code I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'setAttribute'
```

any ideas on how to make this work? I am open to any solution, I just want to have it so that a bar will pulse if it is under a certain value. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` variable won't have the same value in the new context. The following code should work.

```
.each(function(d){
        var that = this;
        if (d<3) {
            setInterval(function(){d3.select(that)
                .attr("fill","black")
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("fill","red")},1000);
        }
});
```